# Implement a function that prints an array using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I need to print an array by implementing the use of a function before the `main` function. So I tried the following function:

```cpp
int* printArr(int* arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << arr[i];
    }   
    return arr;
}
```

I encountered two problems when implementing this into the whole code.

First, this is printing what I think is the address of the array and not the actual array. Pretty sure this is because of the `return arr;` in line 10. But if I do not write `return` then the code will produce an error. How can I fix this?

Second, I do not understand the second argument `printArr` has. In line 19, you can see `cout << printArr(arr, 5) << endl;`. How come there is a single numeric value, that one being 5 in this case, as an argument? How can I account for this in my function?

Please keep in mind that I am new to C++ and coding in general. Also, this code was given to me, hence why I do not understand certain aspects of it.

This is my code so you can see what I mean:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Declare function printArr here

int* printArr(int* arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{cout << arr[i];}
    
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[5] = {1, 3, 5, 7,9};
    int last_num = arr[sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)-1];
    
    cout << "Before reversing" << endl;
    cout << printArr(arr, 5) << endl;
    
    // reverse "arr" using reference(&)
    
    cout << "After reversing" << endl;
    printArr(arr, 5);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What C++ compiler are you using? This should not compile. And the code you show is a mash of C and C++... is this for school?

Comment: `printArr(arr, 5)` should not compile.

Comment: `cout << printArr` is probably not desirable here. `printArr` returns a pointer, so this looks like it would just print the address of `arr` after everything else `printArr` would print.

Comment: In C++ you should be using `std::vector` as your go-to array container. Are you allowed to use that? If not, *sigh*, yet another "C++" course in name only.

Comment: Your `printArr` should take another parameter, `int n` as a number of elements in the array. Also, I don't see why it should return anything at all. may be make it `void`?

Comment: Either `printArr` should *print the array directly*, in which case it has no business being used like `std::cout << printArr(...)` as you should just call it normally, or it should return something that an `ostream` can deal with, which is not currently the case.

Comment: Since this does not compile even though you say it does, I'm voting to close this.

Comment: Yes, I am taking a course in C++. I do not know why it is a combination of C and C++. As stated before this was a skeleton code I was given to build on. It does not compile because of the second argument ``5`` correct? If you eliminate that, it should compile. But as someone said it prints out the address of the array and not the array.

Comment: I have yet to learn about ``std::vector`` however I do realize the array is in C style. I tried to make it ``void`` and not return anything but I get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The declaration and implementation of `printArr()` is all wrong.

> First, this is printing what I think is the address of the array and not the actual array.

The `printArr()` function itself is printing the *contents* of the array (well, the first 5 elements anyway), and then *returning* the address of the array.  It is `main()` that is printing that address afterwards, when it passes the return value of `printArr()` to `std::cout <<`.

> Pretty sure this is because of the `return arr;` in line 10. But if I do not write `return` then the code will produce an error. How can I fix this?

By getting rid of the return type altogether.  There is no good reason to `return` the array pointer at all in this example, let alone to pass that pointer to `std::cout`. So `printArr()` should be returning `void`, ie nothing.

> Second, I do not understand the second argument `printArr` has. In line 19, you can see `cout << printArr(arr, 5) << endl;`. How come there is a single numeric value, that one being 5 in this case, as an argument?

Because `main()` is passing in the element count of the array (5) so that `printArr()` can know how many elements to actually print, instead of hard-coding that value in the loop.  However, your declaration of `printArr()` does not have a 2nd parameter with which to accept that value, that is why you are getting errors.

> How can I account for this in my function?

By adding a 2nd parameter in the function declaration, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Declare function printArr here

void printArr(int* arr, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[5] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
    const int count = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    int last_num = arr[count-1];
    
    cout << "Before reversing" << endl;
    printArr(arr, count);
    
    // reverse "arr" using reference(&)
    
    cout << "After reversing" << endl;
    printArr(arr, count);
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/RSz9ZH)

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanations. I think I now understand what I was doing wrong. I still have a question about that same code. Can I have two functions with the same name ``printArr``? Since you helped me resolve the issue with printing the array using the ``printArr`` function, now I have to reverse it. I was planning on reversing it using another function also named ``printArr``.

Comment: @Rivf "*Can I have two functions with the same name `printArr`?*" - yes, if they have different parameters. It is called **function overloading**. "*I was planning on reversing it using another function also named `printArr`*" - that is not a good idea. Name your functions based on what they actually do. For instance, `reverseArr` would be more appropriate than `printArr` for a function that reverses an array.